# How can I know how many points are used to by the interpolating function returned by NDSolve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, physics

In a problem in which the solution has oscillations that I solved, the amplitude of the oscillations is much lower than I expected. It looks as if the interpolating function doesn't use enough points to plot the results correctly. Has anyone encountered a problem like this before?

It would help a lot if someone could show me a way to deal with this.

The left image shows what I expected, and the right one is what I get.

[image]

The equations are from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/1475-7516/2007/12/010) (also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1998)).

The following is my code; it is a little bit long...

```
f[x_] = x;
n = 50;
\[CapitalEpsilon]\[CapitalEpsilon] = {0, 5.2, 12.4, 19.1, 23.8, 31.3, 
   50};
\[CapitalEpsilon] = 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Flatten[Table[
     N[Rationalize[
       Array[ f, 
        Round[(n (\[CapitalEpsilon]\[CapitalEpsilon][[i + 
               1]] - \[CapitalEpsilon]\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]))/
         50], {\[CapitalEpsilon]\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], \
\[CapitalEpsilon]\[CapitalEpsilon][[i + 1]]}]]], {i, 1, 6}]]];
n = Length[\[CapitalEpsilon]];
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - (10/t)^2])^2;

For[j = 2, j <= n, j++, 
 P[\[CapitalEpsilon][[j]], t] = {Px[\[CapitalEpsilon][[j]], t], 
   Py[\[CapitalEpsilon][[j]], t], Pz[\[CapitalEpsilon][[j]], t]}]
For[j = 2, j <= n, j++, 
 Pbar[\[CapitalEpsilon][[j]], t] = {Pbarx[\[CapitalEpsilon][[j]], t], 
   Pbary[\[CapitalEpsilon][[j]], t], Pbarz[\[CapitalEpsilon][[j]], t]}]

B = {0.02, 0, 0.9998};

\[Zeta] = 1.202;
Ebare = 10;
Ebaree = 15;
Ebarx = 24;
\[Beta]e = 0.315;
\[Beta]ee = 0.21;
\[Beta]x = 0.131;
u = 10^51*(0.197*10^-18)^2*1000*Sqrt[2]*1.16638*10^-5/(3*10^5);
w = 1/0.197;

PP = Table[
   D[P[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], t], t] == 
    w/\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]] Cross[B, P[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], t]] + 
     u \[ScriptCapitalD]*
      Cross[Sum[
        2/(3 \[Zeta]) (((\[Beta]e (\[Beta]e*\[CapitalEpsilon][[
                    i]])^2)/( (E^(\[Beta]e*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]) + 
                   1) Ebare) + (\[Beta]x (\[Beta]x*\[CapitalEpsilon][[
                    i]])^2)/( (E^(\[Beta]x*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]) + 
                   1) Ebarx)) P[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], 
             t] - ((\[Beta]ee (\[Beta]ee*\[CapitalEpsilon][[
                    i]])^2)/( (E^(\[Beta]ee*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]) + 
                   1) Ebaree) + (\[Beta]x \
(\[Beta]x*\[CapitalEpsilon][[
                    i]])^2)/( (E^(\[Beta]x*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]) + 
                   1) Ebarx)) Pbar[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], 
             t]) (\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]] - \[CapitalEpsilon][[i - 
              1]]), {i, 2, n}], P[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], t]], {i, 2, 
    n}];
PV = Table[
   P[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], t] == {0, 
      0, (-((0.00009367045833333334` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]^2)/(
        1 + E^(0.131` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]))) + (
       0.0031255875000000006` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]^2)/(
       1 + E^(0.315` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]])))/((
       0.00009367045833333334` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]^2)/(
       1 + E^(0.131` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]])) + (
       0.0031255875000000006` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]^2)/(
       1 + E^(0.315` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]])))} /. t -> 10, {i, 2, n}];
PbarP = Table[
   D[Pbar[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], t], 
     t] == -w/\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]] Cross[B, 
       Pbar[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], t]] + 
     u \[ScriptCapitalD]*
      Cross[Sum[
        2/(3 \[Zeta]) (((\[Beta]e (\[Beta]e*\[CapitalEpsilon][[
                    i]])^2)/( (E^(\[Beta]e*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]) + 
                   1) Ebare) + (\[Beta]x (\[Beta]x*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]])^2)/( (E^(\[Beta]x*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]) + 
                   1) Ebarx)) P[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], 
             t] - ((\[Beta]ee (\[Beta]ee*\[CapitalEpsilon][[
                    i]])^2)/( (E^(\[Beta]ee*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]) + 
                   1) Ebaree) + (\[Beta]x \
(\[Beta]x*\[CapitalEpsilon][[
                    i]])^2)/( (E^(\[Beta]x*\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]) + 
                   1) Ebarx)) Pbar[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], 
             t]) (\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]] - \[CapitalEpsilon][[i - 
              1]]), {i, 2, n}], Pbar[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], t]], {i, 
    2, n}];
PbarV = Table[
   Pbar[\[CapitalEpsilon][[i]], t] == {0, 
      0, (-((0.00009367045833333334` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]^2)/(
        1 + E^(0.131` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]))) + (
       0.0006173999999999999` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]^2)/(
       1 + E^(0.21` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]])))/((
       0.00009367045833333334` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]^2)/(
       1 + E^(0.131` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]])) + (
       0.0006173999999999999` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]]^2)/(
       1 + E^(0.21` \[CapitalEpsilon][[i]])))} /. t -> 10, {i, 2, 
    n}];
s = Join[PP, PbarP, PV, PbarV];

sss = NDSolve[s,(*Z*)Pz[\[CapitalEpsilon][[5]], t], {t, 10, 200}]
Plot[Pz[\[CapitalEpsilon][[5]], t] /. sss, {t, 10, 200}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {10, 0}, PlotRange -> {{10, 200}, {-1, 1}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

If anyone want to know more clearly about my question(what equation I am solving) and find the paper hard to read, I will show some other code below.

```
  P = {Px[\[CapitalEpsilon], t], Py[\[CapitalEpsilon], t], 
   Pz[\[CapitalEpsilon], t]};
Pbar = {Pbarx[\[CapitalEpsilon], t], Pbary[\[CapitalEpsilon], t], 
   Pbarz[\[CapitalEpsilon], t]};



D[P, t] = {+\[Omega][\[CapitalEpsilon]] B + \[Sqrt]2 Gf \
Integrate[((ne[\[CapitalEpsilon], r] + 
            nx[\[CapitalEpsilon], r]) P - (nebar[\[CapitalEpsilon], 
             r] + nx[\[CapitalEpsilon], 
             r]) Pbar), \[CapitalEpsilon]]}\[Cross]P;

D[Pbar, t] = {-\[Omega][\[CapitalEpsilon]] B + \[Sqrt]2 Gf \
Integrate[((ne[\[CapitalEpsilon], r] + 
            nx[\[CapitalEpsilon], r]) P - (nebar[\[CapitalEpsilon], 
             r] + nx[\[CapitalEpsilon], 
             r]) Pbar), \[CapitalEpsilon]]}\[Cross]Pbar;
```

`\[Omega], B, Gf, ne[\[CapitalEpsilon], r], nx[\[CapitalEpsilon], r], \
    nebar[\[CapitalEpsilon], r], nxbar[\[CapitalEpsilon], r]` are known.

In my origin code before, I try to use discrete `\[CapitalEpsilon]` instead of continuous `\[CapitalEpsilon]`

Comment: 1. This question is unanswerable without seeing your code. 2. Try increasing the `PlotPoints` setting in `Plot[]`, as a first thing to try.

Comment: Ok, I will show my whole code, but I think the question is the  interpolatingfunction solved by NDSolve doesn't have enough points in oscillation.

Comment: The `For[]` bothers me a bit, and I suspect this can be reformulated better. Where did these equations come from? Do you have a book or paper as a source for this?

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. I'm a rookie of MMA, the equations come from a paper of Supernova neutrino, I try to repeat their result as shown in the left picture I upload, but finally what I get is the right one. Because they looks same, so I doubt whether the NDSolve give enough points in the places where oscillate rapidly.

Comment: "paper" - then can you please edit your post to include a citation of the paper?

Comment: Okey, my fault.

Comment: @ 袁子奕 The article is written clumsily and your code is not very clear. Can you write a system of equations that you solve?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I don't really know what you mean "system", but I will try my best to make what I want to solve easily to "read".

Comment: ……The paper is 27 pages long and there're **85** equations listed in that paper, but only a few of them are solved in your code, right? Then, which ones? You mentioned you've discretized the original equation all by yourself, then, in what way? These should be clarified in your question, or we can't even check if the equation is "translated" correctly.

Comment: The authors of the article write that they numerically solve equations (33) - (34). But they do not formulate a model for numerical integration. The reader himself must guess what they decide there and under what conditions. I suspect that the author of the topic solves some similar problem, but not the same one.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing your specific problem, the answer to your initial question is simple:

```
Interpolation[...][[-3,1]]
```

returns the time values of the interpolation-object.

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - x[t]^2, y'[t] == 2 x[t] - y[t]^3, x[0] == y[0] == 1}, 
  {x, y}, {t, 20}]
```

> {{x->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>],y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>]}}

```
Length[(x /. sol[[1]])@"Grid"]
```

> 298

Also

```
Length[(x /. sol[[1]])@"ValuesOnGrid"]
```

> 298

Both match the result from the method suggested in Ulrich Neumann's answer:

```
Length[(x /. sol[[1]])[[3, 1]]]
```

> 298

Comment: Interesting answer, I didn't know the option "Grid", where/how did you find it?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann,  I have seen  `"ValuesOnGrid"` somewhere on this site some time back. `"Grid"` was lucky guess.

Comment: do you think 'StartingStepSize -> 
 1/10, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}' will help to make the InterpolatingFunction have more points?

Comment: @袁子奕,  I don;t know how to control the number of points sampled by  `NDSolve`. I would first try a large value for the option  `PlotPoints`  in `Plot` as suggested by  J. M.issomewhatokay.

Comment: @袁子奕 why are you using the Euler method here? Also, the output of `NDSolve[]` **interpolates**, so your question about "more points" is a bit unreasonable unless you have already tried cranking up `PlotPoints`. In short, you are likely blaming the wrong function for your observations.

Comment: @kglr I try to use PlotPints->20000, but the plot result doesn't change, I think the problem is the InterpolatingFunction doesn't have enough points, but I have no idea how to modify it.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, most data objects can be queried with "Methods"/"Properties" like so: `sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
  y, {x, 0, 30}]; {sol["Methods"], sol["Properties"]}`

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Euler method is just a example given by "help script", when I use 'PlotPoints->20000' to plot the interpolates results given by NDSlove, the result is the same with the right picture I upload. What I want to do is adding the number of point when NDSolve give the 'InterpolatingFunction'. Or do you have other opinion of why I meet this problem.

Comment: Before you take more drastic steps, @袁子奕, please try removing the `Method` setting first in your `NDSolve[]`, so that the automatic method is used and not Euler. If that along with increasing `PlotPoints` does not work, then we have a more interesting problem.

Comment: @Ulrich, if you have a look at the source of the `InterpolatingFunction` Anatomy package in the Add-Ons, you'll see these properties being used behind the scenes.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. In the code I upload, `Method` is not include, `PlotPoints` doesn't work either. Now I wonder maybe what NDSolve give is right and there are some other problems with my function.

Comment: @袁子奕 Notice the initial value problem (IVP) solver of `NDSolve` is very robust, so does `Plot`. So in most cases an unexpected result only suggests one thing: the equations system itself is wrong.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, you are right, finally I find the difference between mine `Plot` and the picture in the reference is because of physical wrong understanding. In other ways  ,it is just like what you said :the equations system itself is wrong.